# React ref is not set correctly inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that passes its size as a prop and renders a child component containing a canvas. It looks like this :

```
const CanvasContainer = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [canvasWidth, setCanvasWidth] = useState(0);
  const [canvasHeight, setCanvasHeight] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;
    if (!container) return;

    setCanvasWidth(container.offsetWidth);
    setCanvasHeight(container.offsetHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <Canvas canvasWidth={canvasWidth} canvasHeight={canvasHeight} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The child component saves a ref to the canvas, creates the canvas context, modifies some properties of the canvas context, and saves this context to another ref.

However, when the context gets saved to the ref, it is saved with its default properties instead of the properties that I had modified.

```
const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (!canvas) return;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) return;

    context.lineCap = 'round';

    console.log(contextRef.current); // Logs null
    contextRef.current = context;
    console.log(contextRef.current); // Logs CanvasRenderingContext2D but lineCap is still set to its default value ('butt' instead of 'round')
  }, []);

  const { canvasWidth, canvasHeight } = props;

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried to replace `useEffect` with `useLayoutEffect` but it doesn't change anything.

I noticed that this bug is not occurring when I add `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` to the `useEffect` dependency array.

Is this behavior expected or is this some kind of bug ?

Live Example:

```js
const {useRef, useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect} = React;

const CanvasContainer = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [canvasWidth, setCanvasWidth] = useState(0);
  const [canvasHeight, setCanvasHeight] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;
    if (!container) return;

    setCanvasWidth(container.offsetWidth);
    setCanvasHeight(container.offsetHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <Canvas canvasWidth={canvasWidth} canvasHeight={canvasHeight} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (!canvas) return;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) return;

    context.lineCap = 'round';
    console.log(context.lineCap);

    console.log(contextRef.current); // Logs null
    contextRef.current = context;
    console.log(contextRef.current); // Logs CanvasRenderingContext2D but lineCap is still set to its default value ('butt' instead of 'round')
    console.log(contextRef.current.lineCap);
  }, []);

  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);

  const startDrawing = (event) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = event.nativeEvent;

    if (!contextRef.current) return
    console.log(contextRef.current.lineCap); // Logs 'butt' instead of 'round'
    
    contextRef.current.beginPath();
    contextRef.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);

    setIsDrawing(true);
  };

  const draw = (event) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = event.nativeEvent;
    
    if (!contextRef.current) return
    contextRef.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    contextRef.current.stroke();
  };

  const stopDrawing = () => {
    if (!contextRef.current) return
    contextRef.current.closePath();
    
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  const { canvasWidth, canvasHeight } = props;

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
      // Event Handlers
      onMouseDown={startDrawing}
      onMouseMove={draw}
      onMouseUp={stopDrawing}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CanvasContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#root > div {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Where to use contextRef ?

Comment: I've added a stack snippet to your question. When I log `contextRef.current.lineCap` (rather than logging the full object), I see `"round"` as expected. This seems like it could just be a console thing. Is there any actual bug in your code that you can demonstrate with this? Rather than just a value in teh console?

Comment: Just tried to log `contextRef.current.lineCap` and it logs `'round'` for me too. 
However it still logs `'butt'` inside other functions later in the code. I edited the code snippet to add these functions.

Comment: Check your hooks dependencies and try shallow copying your context instead of just copying it by reference.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I noticed that the bug disappears when I add `canvasRef.current` or `containerRef.current` inside `useEffect` dependencies . However, I read somewhere that refs should not be added inside `useEffect` dependencies. Is it true ? I also tried to shallow copy the `context` object (both with spread operator and Object.assign()) but it doesn't work : the new object is empty, even though `context` is not undefined.

Comment: Dependencies arrays are used primarily to determine when a certain callback is obsolete and needs to be discarded and replaced with a fresh one. In the case of hooks like `useCallback` indeed it would be completely unnecessary to add a `ref` or `ref.value` as a dependency because `ref` never changes and its value (`ref.current`) will always be up to date ('by reference'). (Continues...)

Comment: For `useEffect` hooks the same logic applies, with the exception that a `useEffect` callback will only fire when one of its dependencies change. So, your `ref.current` value could always be up to date, thus the original callback will still be valid, but if you want your hook to fire when your `ref.current` value changes you have to add it to the dependencies. Adding only `ref` makes no sense because it never changes even if its current value does.